# Why Does Windows 10 Forget my Taskbar Preferences During Upgrade

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-10-upgrade

Pretty simple question - Why, every time my machine does a Windows 10 feature upgrade, does it lose all my taskbar preferences and what I can do to resolve?

Comment: They are reset because a feature upgrade results in Windows being reinstalled, there really isn't a way, to prevent the behavior you describe

Comment: But it carries over my other documents and settings? So there must be a way to prevent the behaviour. Maybe not by me, but by Microsoft there is...

Comment: Your profile is moved to another location on the HDD, then added back to the new installation, not everything is possible.  The settings are being "reset" because new features are being added, which have defaults, so for whatever reason Microsoft chooses to reset all settings.  You can avoid this by syncing your settings between multiple accounts and a link local profile.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound i'll give the multiple accounts and link profile thing a go!